# Partial Ordering and Hasse Diagram.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

Draw the Hasse diagram for the partial ordering “x is a factor of y” on the following sets:

S = {2, 3, 5, 7, 21, 42, 105, 210}

I don't know how to find the partial ordering of this set. I know that to be a partial order it needs to be reflexive, anti symmetric and transitive.

However, this is my Hasse diagram.

[image: photo]

Comment: This needs a line from 2 to 42 because 2|42. Also 42|210 so another line needed.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've edited the diagram. However, I'm having a hard time understanding how the "poset" is working in this case.

Comment: Did you know that $3\mid 21$ and $21 \mid 42$?

Comment: Yes, there should be a line from 21 to 42.